# Set variable from function with possible ajax-load inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have made my own script for loading content with AJAX if nor already loaded. Here it is:

```
/*
 * AJAX Load Content
 */

var loaded_content_urls = {};

function get_content_from_url(url)
{
        if (loaded_content_urls[url] === undefined)
        {
            $.ajax({url: url}).done(function(data)
            {
                loaded_content_urls[url] = data;

                return data;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return loaded_content_urls[url];
        }
}
```

And I wanna use it like this:

```
var loaded_html = get_content_from_url($(this).attr('href') + '?ajax');
```

But that won't work great since it can take a while for the content to be loaded and the variable above needs the value directly. So how should I do this?

I did a search about the issue but only found solutions where you always loads the content with AJAX. My code is special in that way that it first checks if the content already have been loaded. So I can't just have the AJAX function as return of the function.

Comment: Have you consider using  jQuery.Deferred()(https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)? If this is something you are looking for, I can write an answer for this

Comment: @kishorekumaru I'm not sure I understand. Can I use `object.promise()` even if I haven't run the ajax before? For when the content already is loded.

Comment: if my solution works for you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Your example code should like below:

```
var urlData = ''
  function get_content_from_url (url) {
    var _defer = jQuery.Deferred();

    if( urlData === undefined){
      $.ajax({url: url}).done(function(data){
        urlData = data;
          _defer.resolve(urlData);
        });
    } else{
      _defer.resolve(urlData);
    }
    return _defer.promise();
  };

$.when(get_content_from_url(url)).then( function( data) {
  var loaded_html = data;
});
```

I will also suggest to use reject and fail method to handle error scenarios